# delete special object from vector c++

Tags: c++, vector, erase

I have a vector of int

```
vector<int> p;
```

now I want to delete one of its items that is equal to 3.
there is no remove like p.remove(3)

but there is a erase but at first I should I find it.
there were two questions about this available in stackoverflow. both of them said that we should find it by

```
std::remove(p.begin(), p.end(), 3)
```

but this code isn't compiled. it said function does not take 3 arguments.

Comment: Show us what you have tried at least. Obviously you are not using it correctly somehow, because it does take 3 arguments

Comment: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/remove/

Comment: it is easy just see what is in 1st answer. or continue downvoting

Comment: A good answer doesn't make your question better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [Erase Remove Idiom](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erase-remove_idiom) .

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector> 

int main()
{
    using namespace std;
    vector<int> v = {1, 2, 3, 3, 4};

    v.erase(find(begin(v), end(v), 3));  // remove first 3
    // v.erase(remove(begin(v), end(v), 3), end(v));  // remove all 3

    copy(begin(v), end(v), ostream_iterator<int>(cout, " "));
}
```

Vectors `erase` method takes one or two iterators. The first one, erases everthing from the specified position to the end.
`std::remove` from `<algorithm>` moves all matching elements to the end of the sequence and returns an iterator to the position of the new end. You can use this iterator for `erase`.
If you want to remove the first matching element, use `std::find` to retrieve an iterator to the first element and pass that to `erase`.

Comment: Does this remove all `5`'s in the vector?

Comment: Yes, if you want to delete the first occuraence you might want to use `std::find` as input for `erase`

Comment: Well, to quote the question - "now I want to delete **one of its items** that is equal to 3." (emphasis mine)

Comment: @hansmaad function does not take 3 arguments

Answer (score 1):

use `remove_if` found under `algorithm`

Given a begin and end iterator along with a predicate, you can remove any element that results in the predicate evaluating to true. I'll include both C++03 and C++11 examples.

C++03:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <vector>

#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>

template <typename T>
struct
is_equal
{
  T val;
  is_equal (const T& v) : val (v) { }
  bool
  operator() (const T& test)
  {
    return (val == test);
  }
};

struct
is_odd
{
  bool
  operator() (int test)
  {
    return (test % 2 == 1);
  }
};

template <typename T>
std::ostream&
operator<< (std::ostream& os, const std::vector <T>& v)
{
  typedef typename std::vector <T>::const_iterator itr;
  for (itr i = v.begin (); i != v.end (); ++i)
    os << *i << " ";
  return os;
}

int
main (int argc, char* argv[])
{
  srand (time (NULL));
  std::vector <int> vec (10);  // vector has size of 10
  std::generate (vec.begin (), vec.end (), rand); // populate with random numbers
  std::cout << vec << std::endl;
  vec.erase (std::remove_if (vec.begin (), vec.end (), is_odd ()), // removes all odd elements
             vec.end ());
  std::cout << vec << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

C++11:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <numeric>
#include <vector>

#include <cstdlib>

template<typename T>
std::ostream&
operator<< (std::ostream& os, const std::vector <T>& v)
{
  for (auto i : v)
    os << i << " ";
  return os;
}

int
main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  std::vector <int> vec(10);  // vector has size of 10
  std::iota (vec.begin(), vec.end(), 1); // populate with [1, 2, 3, ...]
  std::cout << vec << std::endl;
  vec.erase (std::remove_if (vec.begin(), vec.end(),
                             [](int i){ return (i == 3); }),
             vec.end ());
  std::cout << vec << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

For any questions on using the STL, I personally consult http://en.cppreference.com/w/ and http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/

Comment: That's a bit overkill. Why use a predicate when you just want an exact match?

Comment: This works for any situation where you need to remove based on some criteria. This merely establishes a framework that can be reused to fit further needs.

Answer (score 0):

Use `std::vector::erase` combined with `std::find`.

You can look at the documentation here:

- http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/vector/erase/
- http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/find/

Comment: there is no find function either. I included vector and used namesapace std

Comment: @MHabibi if there's no find function in std, your compiler is broken.

Comment: @MHabibi btw, did you bother to follow the links and see the examples?

Comment: I saw them. both of them. and copied them. but it doesn't work. I am using visual studio 2010